# What is this sink drain bolt called?

Tags: plumbing

A bolt that holds the kitchen sink drain "basket" to the sink basin has broken and caused water to leak between the sink and the drain. What is this part called?

[image]

[image]

Also, any ideas on where I can find it in Canada? So far what I've seen for sale are only entire "sink strainer" assemblies, when I just need that bolt.

Comment: Any bolt of the correct thread pitch would work. I'd suggest taking it to your local hardware store and browsing the selection until you find one that matches. I _would_ recommend stainless steel so it doesn't rust and/or get nasty looking. Galvanized steel would be a second place. Bare steel would be a very distant 3rd, and I'd invest in a box of them so you can replace them when they start to look nasty.

Comment: @FreeMan  Taking it to local store might be difficult right now, depending where in Canada OP is.  Quite a few places are in lock down again.

Comment: I would go stainless or brass, galvanized steel in a drain the zinc won’t last long acidic fruits and vegetables or even things like pickle juice will remove the zinc.

Comment: Google does bring up bolts that look like that if search for 'sink strainer bolts'.  If you know make of sink, then might be able to find right size bolt.

Comment: I don't think it is worth finding a replacement, which can be costly. IMO, replace the whole set is more realistic then. I believe the strainer is operated through the hole in the middle of the shank, is that correct?

Comment: @r13, that's the answer, it is not worth trying to find that maker specific part, the OP needs a new sink drain assembly. Post it and I will vote it up.

Comment: A M12x40 bolt did the trick. 35mm would have been fine too. The material was not indicated but it was the only one I found in the store. It is shiny silver, so hopefully stainless steel. The strainer assemblies are quite expensive, easily $20-$40+. This <$2 solution is not perfect as the original strainer won't fit, but we were already using a different strainer. So, problem solved for now. Thanks for all the comments!

Comment: @Jack Thanks for your support. It seems the OP has found the solution for less than $2 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A standard M12x40 bolt from a hardware store did the trick. 35mm would be fine as well.

[image: https://www.albanycountyfasteners.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/20170811_144120-768x787.jpg]

One compromise is that since the center is not hollow, it will block the original strainer from seating properly. Still, at <$2 this solution is 10-20X cheaper than buying a whole strainer assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Any bolt of the correct thread pitch would work. I'd suggest taking it to your local hardware store and browsing the selection until you find one that matches. I would recommend stainless steel so it doesn't rust and/or get nasty looking, brass would be a good alternative, though it wouldn't match in terms of color. Galvanized steel would be a second place. Bare steel would be a very distant 3rd, and I'd invest in a box of them so you can replace them when they start to look nasty.

Comment: Thanks, the only downside of this to keep in mind is that the strainer no longer fits as it used to clip into the hole of the original hollow bolt. Other than that, it is a cheap and simple solution compared to purchasing a whole strainer assembly. Unfortunately the original bolt hasn't been easy to find.